# Want to load seed data before running cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I want cucumber to load my seed data in "db/seeds.rb" before starting to test. Not before each scenario or feature, but only once before running the tests. 
And also after each scenario, the seeds must remain in db.

Is that possible?

I've tried creating a file "features/support/seed_data.rb" and requiring my db/seeds.rb in there, but it seems that file is not loaded at all. I tried to require my seeds in env.rb - no affect.

Please, can anybody suggest me the solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Create a before hook in your support/hooks.rb file which looks like this:

```
Before('@load-seed-data') do
  load File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.rb')
end
```

In your test before the scenario, call the hook like this:

```
@load-seed-data @US49
Scenario: This is a scenario that needs seed data.
Given...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about pulling the code from your seeds.rb file and sticking it in hooks.rb in an AfterConfiguration block?

```
AfterConfiguration do |config|
  # Your code from seeds.rb
end
```

That should be called [once](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Hooks) during a run, right after cucumber is configured. At least doing it this way, you can determine if you just have an issue with including your seeds file or not.  Another idea would be to take seeds.rb and stick it directly inside the support directory as a module and then call it from AfterConfiguration:

```
# db_seeds.rb
module DbSeeds 

  def seed_db
    # Your Code
  end

end

World(DbSeeds)

#hooks.rb
AfterConfiguration do |config|
  seed_db
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But this still doesn't work, coz after each scenario cucumber cleans the database with all the seeds (.

Comment: The real question is why is cucumber cleaning the DB when you're seeding it once.