# Cucumber's AfterConfiguration can't access helper modules

Tags: sinatra, cucumber

I have a modular Sinatra app without a DB and in order to test memcache, I have some test files that need to be created and deleted on the file system. I would like to generate these files in an AfterConfiguration hook using some helper methods (which are in a module shared with rspec, which also needs to create/delete these files for testing). I only want to create them once at the start of Cucumber.

I do not seem to be able to access the helpers from within AfterConfiguration, which lives in "support/hooks.rb." The helpers are accessible from Cucumber's steps, so I know they have been loaded properly.

This previous post seems to have an answer: [Want to load seed data before running cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296270/want-to-load-seed-data-before-running-cucumber)

The second example in this answer seems to say my modules should be accessible to my AfterConfiguration block, but I get "undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass" when attempting to call helper method "foo".

I can pull everything out into a rakefile and run it that way, but I'd like to know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around in the code, it appears that AfterConfiguration not only runs before any features are loaded, but before World is instantiated. Running self.class inside of the AfterConfig block returns NilClass. Running self.class inside of any other hook, such as a Before, will return MyWorldName. In retrospect, this makes sense as every feature is run in a separate instance of World.

This is why helpers defined as instance methods (ie def method_name) are unknown. Changing my methods to module methods (ie def ModuleName.method_name) allows them to function, since they really are module methods anyway.